# Does Flutter recycle images in a ListView?

Tags: android, http, caching, flutter, infinite-scroll

I would like to make an endlessFeed in Fluter but the app terminates without giving me any information why. Basically it happens after I scrolled down about 60 images then it starts to lag a bit and it crashes.

I tested another API but the same there. It uses images with lower resolution so it takes longer to scroll down until it stops working.

So I don't know what happens here. My guess is that there are to many images in the ListView so that the phone can't handle it and crashes. 
I've put the whole code below because I don't even know wehere the problem could be. Is there maybe another way to achieve an endlessImageFeed?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

// my base url
String imageUrl = "http://192.168.2.107:8000";




void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'EndlessFeed',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: PhotoList(),

    );
  }
}

class PhotoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PhotoListState createState() => PhotoListState();

}

class PhotoListState extends State<PhotoList> {
  StreamController<Photo> streamController;
  List<Photo> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamController = StreamController.broadcast();

    streamController.stream.listen((p) => setState(() => list.add(p)));

    load(streamController);

  }

  load(StreamController<Photo> sc) async {

    // URL for API
    String url = "http://192.168.2.107:8000/api/";
    /* ______________________________________________
    I also tried another API but it chrashes also (but it takes longer until crash):
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/";
    ______________________________________________ */


    var client = new http.Client();

    var req = new http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url));

    var streamedRes = await client.send(req);

    streamedRes.stream
        .transform(UTF8.decoder)
        .transform(json.decoder)
        .expand((e) => e)
        .map((map) => Photo.fromJsonMap(map))
        .pipe(sc);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    streamController?.close();
    streamController = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("EndlessFeed"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _makeElement(index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _makeElement(int index) {
    if (index >= list.length) {
      return null;
    }

    return Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

                child: new Container(

                  // my base URL + one image
                  child: new Image(image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageUrl + list[index].mImage))

                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Photo {
  final String mImage;

  Photo.fromJsonMap(Map map)
      : mImage= map['mImage'];
}
```

Comment: what flutter version are you using?

Comment: @JonahWilliams 0.5.1